# How to extract data from string using Python RegEx?

Tags: python, regex, lookbehind

I have file names in this format :

```
INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218_19-May-2014_13-09-59.121._OK
INC_2EE_22RE_1560343444_119_11-Jun-2014_15-21-32.329._OK
INC_2CD_22HY_1652323334_312_21-Jan-2014_11-15-48.291._OK
```

I want to extract the name before the date part. For instance, anything before **`_19-May-2014_13-09-59.121._`OK** is desired in first file yielding **`INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218`**

I tried lookback method but unable to wrap my head around this at the moment.

Essential, trying to match this pattern `_[0-9]-[aA-bB]-*`

Comment: is there always the same number of items separated by underscores before the date?

Comment: is there always the same number of characters before the date?

Comment: Internet Explorer was not letting me reply yesterday. It is not fixed width though the number of underscores are always fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below code,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218_19-May-2014_13-09-59.121._OK
... INC_2EE_22RE_1560343444_119_11-Jun-2014_15-21-32.329._OK
... INC_2CD_22HY_1652323334_312_21-Jan-2014_11-15-48.291._OK"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'^.*?(?=_\d{2}-[A-Z][a-z]{2}-\d{4})', s, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218
INC_2EE_22RE_1560343444_119
INC_2CD_22HY_1652323334_312
```

Answer (score 3):

If your format is consistent you could use the following.

```
>>> s = 'INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218_19-May-2014_13-09-59.121._OK'
>>> '_'.join(s.split('_')[0:5])
'INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218'
```

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: This splits on an underscore and then joins list items 0 through 5 with an underscore creating your original format.

Comment: @ThinkCode: Could you describe exactly the format of your string?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.*(?=_\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3})
```

It uses a lookahead assertion for the `_00-Aaa` format of the date you have there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the lines have a standard size. Just use

```
offset = len('INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218')`
for line in input:
     print line[:offset]
```

Comment: If the length is always the same, it is the best answer.

Comment: Note that if you know it in advance, you don't need to use len. But I assume that it is only here to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since your desired data is at the start of the line, anchors make a search fairly easy:

```
^(.*)(?:_\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/F26RxkB67VSeFoUm)

```
>>> import re
>>> txt='''\
... INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218_19-May-2014_13-09-59.121._OK
... INC_2EE_22RE_1560343444_119_11-Jun-2014_15-21-32.329._OK
... INC_2CD_22HY_1652323334_312_21-Jan-2014_11-15-48.291._OK'''
>>> 
>>> re.findall(r'^(.*)(?:_\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{4})', txt, re.M)
['INC_2AB_22BA_1300435674_218', 'INC_2EE_22RE_1560343444_119', 'INC_2CD_22HY_1652323334_312']
```

If you want to be even more specific of matching `'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'` in the date field, you can do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^([^-]+)(?:_\d{2}-(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4})', txt, re.M)
```

... same output

Comment: It's not very different from Avanish Raj answer but it may be a little faster due to the length of the string before and after the date.

Comment: To reduce the amount of backtracking, you can replace `.` with `[^-]`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. If the length is always the same, following regular expression may be used as well

```
^([^$]{27})
```

Or this one

```
^(.{27})
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pF1tP2/1)

Comment: You're better off using `^.{27}`

Comment: Using a regex to get the first 27th characters of a string is overkill and slower than using indexes; see fabrizioM answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You might be right; just wanted to add another solution :)